# Installing IEEEtrantools.sty on Yosemite with BasicTeX

Tags: installing

I'm trying to install the `IEEEtrantools.sty` package. I am running Yosemite and have a fresh BasicTeX package installed, not upgraded. I have updated `tlmgr` from the command line via `sudo`.

```
 $sudo tlmgr install IEEEtrantools.sty
```

returns the error that the package isn't found in the repository

so I downloaded the package onto my desktop and

```
$sudo tlmgr install ~/Desktop/IEEEtrantools.sty
```

still isn't found

So I figured I'd try TexLiveUtility, downloaded it, installed it, and it can't find a valid server (listing failed.) I tried the advice to reinstall Tex Live Manager (can't find the server) even though I'd just updated it from the command line not 10 minutes previous (and restarted for good measure.)

Action -> Refresh Package List naturally returns listing failed.

I've a new machine, and I'm attempting to use existing tex files that require IEEEtrantools.

Could someone pls tell me what I need to do in order to use this package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX Live packages are a different thing from LaTeX packages; for `IEEEtrantools.sty` you need `sudo tlmgr install IEEEtran`. But why not installing the full MacTeX and forget about manually installing packages? You just need to run TeX Live Utility once a month for upgrades.

Comment: Thank you and thank you. Does there exist a TeX Live package list?

Comment: Launch TeX Live Utility, Packages tab; but finding individual files is difficult.

Comment: @egreg `tlmgr` can search by file name. Isn't that searching for individual files?

Comment: @cfr Yes, it is.

Comment: @egreg Then you just meant it is difficult using the GUI wrapper? Not that it is difficult tout court?

Comment: As @egreg says, TeX Live Utility searches based on package name and description, not by filename. I'm more concerned that you can't find a valid server, but I'll need more info. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used TeX Live Utility, but TeX Live Manager can search for packages by filename if the `--file` option is used. By default, it searches locally installed packages, but `--global` can be used to search the repository.

For example:

```
$ tlmgr search --global --file IEEEtrantools.sty
tlmgr: package repository http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
IEEEtran:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtrantools.sty
lshort-spanish:
        texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-spanish/fuente/src/IEEEtrantools.sty
```

Comment: Thanks cfr, but I still can't install it with that filename

Comment: @zazizoma You can't tell it just to install the file. You can search for the file and then install the package. But you can't just install that particular file. Nor, usually, would doing so do you much good. Certainly `titlesec` includes a number of files, apart from documentation etc.

Comment: Okay, so lets say I need to install titlesec. I can find it with the find command you demonstrated, but is there a mystery name for it like IEEEtran for tex live? If so, how do I find it for use on the command line.

Comment: btw in this case just plain titlesec worked . . .

Comment: @zazizoma Look at the output I posted. How would you know it was `IEEEtran`? Because it says `IEEEtran`. It gives you the package name and the location of the file. It is pretty straightforward, to be honest.

Comment: Oh yes, I see it! Super, thanks. I feel empowered to move forward.

Comment: @zazizoma Excellent! `tlmgr` is under-appreciated, I think ;).